# Batch File Can't Access Folder When Trying to Move

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file with the following code which at the line

```
move "%UserProfile%\Desktop\System" "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
```

is supposed to move the System folder on the Desktop to `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` but it says a file is in use so it can't be moved

The code of the batch file is

```
@echo off

del /q /f "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"

del /q /f "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Microsoft Edge.lnk"

del /f /s /q /a "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*"

REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband /F

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe

cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"

mkdir "Accessories"
mkdir "Admin Tools"
mkdir "System"

move "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\*.lnk" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Accessories"
move "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\*.lnk" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Accessories"
move "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\System Tools\*.lnk" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Accessories"

move "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessibility\*.lnk" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Accessories"
move "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessibility\*.lnk" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Accessories"

move "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\*.lnk" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\System"

move "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\*.lnk" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\System"
move "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\*.lnk" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\System"

move "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\*.lnk" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Admin Tools"

cacls "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" /t /e /g Administrators:f

cd "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"

rmdir /s /q "Accessories"
rmdir /s /q "Administrative Tools"
rmdir /s /q "Accessibility"
rmdir /s /q "System Tools"

cacls "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" /t /e /g Administrators:f

cd "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"

rmdir /s /q "Accessories"
rmdir /s /q "Administrative Tools"
rmdir /s /q "Accessibility"
rmdir /s /q "Windows PowerShell"
rmdir /s /q "System Tools"

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe

cd "%UserProfile%\Desktop\System"

ren "computer.lnk" "This PC.lnk"

move "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Accessories" "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
move "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Admin Tools" "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
move "%UserProfile%\Desktop\System" "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe

pause
```

Comment: The error is relatively clear: a file is in use and therefore cant be moved.

Comment: How can I tell which file is in use and how can I stop a process/program from using that file so that I can proceed with moving the file?

Comment: How to know who has a file locked is the subject for another question. For starters, look into the sysinternals tool handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The CWD is the folder you're trying to move.**

These are the offending lines

```
cd "%UserProfile%\Desktop\System"



move "%UserProfile%\Desktop\System" "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
```

You've changed the current working directory (CWD) to `%UserProfile%\Desktop\System` and then attempted to move that very directory.

Some programs might be clever enough to figure out what you want, but cmd.exe is not one of them. It inherently locks the CWD. (I think it also locks any other directories on the directory stack—PUSHD/POPD.)

First, CD to a different directory before attempting to move `%UserProfile%\Desktop\System`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes complete sense why. You've solved my issue. I just changed the directory before the move command.